# React REDUX is updating all state after the update action

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, material-ui, formik

I've been figuring out this bug since yesterday.

All of the states are working before the update action. I have console log all the states before the update action.
[image]

Then after creating a model, the update action is executed.
This is the result when I console log.
[image]

I wondered why dataGrid returns an error since I point to all the id in the DataGrid component.

```
Uncaught Error: MUI: The data grid component requires all rows to have a unique `id` property.
```

[image]

This is my code:
Models Reducer:

```
import * as actionTypes from 'constants/actionTypes';

export default (models = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_MODELS:
            return action.payload.result;
        case actionTypes.CREATE:
            return [...models, action.payload.result];
        case actionTypes.UPDATE:
            return models.map((model) => (model.model_id === action.payload.result.model_id ? action.payload.result : model));
        case actionTypes.DELETE:
            return models.filter((model) => model.model_id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return models;
    }
};
```

In my model component:

```
import * as actionTypes from 'constants/actionTypes';

export default (models = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_MODELS:
            return action.payload.result;
        case actionTypes.CREATE:
            return [...models, action.payload.result];
        case actionTypes.UPDATE:
            return models.map((model) => (model.model_id === action.payload.result.model_id ? action.payload.result : model));
        case actionTypes.DELETE:
            return models.filter((model) => model.model_id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return models;
    }
};
```

My ModelForm:

```
<Formik
            enableReinitialize={true}
            initialValues={modelData}
            validationSchema={Yup.object().shape({
                model_code: Yup.string(4).min(4, 'Minimum value is 4.').max(50, 'Maximum value is 4.').required('Model code is required'),
                model_description: Yup.string().max(200, 'Maximum value is 200.'),
                model_status: Yup.string().min(5).max(10, 'Maximum value is 10.')
            })}
            onSubmit={async (values, { setErrors, setStatus, setSubmitting }) => {
                try {
                    if (scriptedRef.current) {
                        if (currentId === 0) {
                            // , name: user?.result?.name
                            dispatch(createModel({ ...values }, setFormVisible));
                        } else {
                            dispatch(updateModel(currentId, { ...values }, setFormVisible));
                        }
                        setStatus({ success: true });
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }
                } catch (err) {
                    console.error(err);
                    if (scriptedRef.current) {
                        setStatus({ success: false });
                        setErrors({ submit: err.message });
                        setSubmitting(false);
                    }
                }
            }}
        >
            {({ errors, handleBlur, handleChange, handleSubmit, isSubmitting, touched, resetForm, values }) => (
                <form noValidate onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                    <Grid container spacing={1}>
                        <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12}>
                            <JTextField
                                label="Model"
                                name="model_code"
                                value={values.model_code}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                touched={touched}
                                errors={errors}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    <Grid container spacing={1} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                        <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12}>
                            <JTextField
                                label="Description"
                                name="model_description"
                                value={values.model_description}
                                onBlur={handleBlur}
                                onChange={handleChange}
                                touched={touched}
                                type="multiline"
                                rows={4}
                                errors={errors}
                            />
                        </Grid>
                    </Grid>
                    {currentId ? (
                        <Grid container spacing={1} sx={{ mt: 1 }}>
                            <Grid item lg={4} md={4} sm={12}>
                                <JSelect
                                    labelId="model_status"
                                    id="model_status"
                                    name="model_status"
                                    value={values.model_status}
                                    label="Status"
                                    onBlur={handleBlur}
                                    onChange={handleChange}
                                    errors={errors}
                                >
                                    <MenuItem value="ACTIVE">ACTIVE</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem value="INACTIVE">INACTIVE</MenuItem>
                                </JSelect>
                            </Grid>
                        </Grid>
                    ) : (
                        ''
                    )}
                    <Box sx={{ mt: 2 }}>
                        <ButtonGroup variant="contained" aria-label="outlined button group">
                            <Button size="small" disabled={isSubmitting} type="submit">
                                Save
                            </Button>
                            <Button size="small" onClick={resetForm}>
                                Cancel
                            </Button>
                            {currentId ? (
                                <Button size="small" color="secondary" onClick={handleDelete}>
                                    Delete
                                </Button>
                            ) : (
                                ''
                            )}
                        </ButtonGroup>
                    </Box>
                </form>
            )}
        </Formik>
```

Why products, parts or other states are updating too? Since I only update the model create action?

Please check this out: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/11412230?key=a0212021c59aa1097fa9d38917399fe3

I Hope someone could help me figure out this bug. This is only the problem else my CRUD template is good.

Comment: Everything works normally until I create a model. Please the link provided above thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update**:
Found out that actions in redux should always be unique or else multiple reducers with the same action name will be triggered.

I have updated my action types to:

```
// AUTHENTICATION ACTIONS
export const AUTH = 'AUTH';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';

// MODEL ACTIONS
export const FETCH_MODELS = 'FETCH_MODELS';
export const CREATE_MODEL = 'CREATE_MODEL';
export const UPDATE_MODEL = 'UPDATE_MODEL';
export const DELETE_MODEL = 'DELETE_MODEL';

// PRODUCTS ACTIONS
export const FETCH_PRODUCTS = 'FETCH_PRODUCTS';
export const CREATE_PRODUCT = 'CREATE_PRODUCT';
export const UPDATE_PRODUCT = 'UPDATE_PRODUCT';
export const DELETE_PRODUCT = 'DELETE_PRODUCT';

// ASSEMBLY ACTIONS
export const FETCH_ASSEMBLY = 'FETCH_ASSEMBLY';
export const CREATE_ASSEMBLY = 'CREATE_ASSEMBLY';
export const UPDATE_ASSEMBLY = 'UPDATE_ASSEMBLY';
export const DELETE_ASSEMBLY = 'DELETE_ASSEMBLY';

// PARTS ACTIONS
export const FETCH_PARTS = 'FETCH_PARTS';
export const CREATE_PART = 'CREATE_PART';
export const UPDATE_PART = 'UPDATE_PART';
export const DELETE_PART = 'DELETE_PART';
```

Reducers to:

```
import * as actionTypes from 'constants/actionTypes';

export default (models = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_MODELS:
            return action.payload.result;
        case actionTypes.CREATE_MODEL:
            return [...models, action.payload.result];
        case actionTypes.UPDATE_MODEL:
            console.log(models);
            return models.map((model) => (model.model_id === action.payload.result.model_id ? action.payload.result : model));
        case actionTypes.DELETE_MODEL:
            return models.filter((model) => model.model_id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return models;
    }
};
```

and Actions to:

```
import * as actionTypes from 'constants/actionTypes';
import * as api from 'api/index.js';
import Swal from 'sweetalert2';

export const getModels = () => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.fetchModels();
        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.FETCH_MODELS, payload: data });
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire('Error!', 'Something went wrong', 'error');
    }
};

export const createModel = (model, setFormVisible) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.createModel(model);

        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.CREATE_MODEL, payload: data });
        setFormVisible(false);

        Swal.fire('Success!', 'Model has been added successfully', 'success');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire('Error!', 'Something went wrong', 'error');
    }
};

export const updateModel = (id, model, setFormVisible) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        const { data } = await api.updateModel(id, model);

        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.UPDATE_MODEL, payload: data });
        setFormVisible(false);
        Swal.fire('Success!', 'Model updated successfully', 'success');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire('Error!', 'Something went wrong', 'error');
    }
};

export const deleteModel = (id) => async (dispatch) => {
    try {
        await await api.deleteModel(id);

        dispatch({ type: actionTypes.DELETE_MODEL, payload: id });
        Swal.fire('Success!', 'Model deleted successfully', 'success');
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
        Swal.fire('Error!', 'Something went wrong', 'error');
    }
};
```