# What is the best way to return a create action in REDUX?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui, formik

I have a problem in update action to my states because when I call that create action it also updates the other state.

This is the main thread since no one is able to answer: [React REDUX is updating all state after the update action](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902831/react-redux-is-updating-all-state-after-the-update-action).

My question is this how should we return in a create action in redux?

```
import * as actionTypes from 'constants/actionTypes';

export default (models = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case actionTypes.FETCH_MODELS:
            return action.payload.result;
        case actionTypes.CREATE:
            return [...models, action.payload.result];
        case actionTypes.UPDATE:
            return models.map((model) => (model.model_id === action.payload.result.model_id ? action.payload.result : model));
        case actionTypes.DELETE:
            return models.filter((model) => model.model_id !== action.payload);
        default:
            return models;
    }
};
```

Check this video: https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/video/11414546?key=17bb5b0fac4a93040cc890635c6df4b8

Comment: Do you have any errors ? a reproducible sample helps to debug ... you can use codesandbox etc., for making one

Comment: Yes on this thread, but now able to figure out that action names should be unique per reducers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73902831/react-redux-is-updating-all-state-after-the-update-action